# How to use AWS lambda in java for Amazon lex

Tags: java, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I want to use aws lambda in java for Amazon lex. But there is no any reference or blueprint on aws site.
I am confused with how to take request and send response to lex
What is tha format of request and response ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the details about the input and output formats in the AWS Lex Documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html

Answer (score 0):

There's always the `com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.LexEvent` you can start with for a Lambda function. review `intents`, `invocation source`, and `slots`. From there you can revisit https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/context-mgmt.html to understand how to begin managing interactions between a user and a bot.